# Update record using PHP/PDO and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to update a record in my table however im receiving the following error...

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`First_Name`,`Surname`,`Nicknames`' at line 1Number of rows added: Go back
```

My code is as follows....

```
// Connection data (server_address, database, name, poassword)
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = '_co_';
$userdb = '';
$passdb = '';

try {
  // Connect and create the PDO object
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $sql = "UPDATE `directory` (`First_Name`,`Surname`,`Nicknames`) 
      VALUES (:firstname, :surname, :nicknames)
      WHERE ID = :cid

      ;



      ";



 $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $statement->bindValue(":cid", $cid);
 $statement->bindValue(":firstname", $firstname);
 $statement->bindValue(":surname", $surname);
 $statement->bindValue(":nicknames", $nicknames);
```

Comment: You just mixed `INSERT` syntax with `UPDATE` it looks like. When problem, look manual. Helps often fast and manual has good information next to some basic syntax, too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html - I must admit when I digged through this, I even did have internet and such manuals at my fingertips. So make use from the possibilities you've got, you should be able to learn much faster.

Comment: Bad question. The error message says it all: _check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is wrong:

```
UPDATE `directory`
SET `First_Name` = :firstname, `Surname` = :surname, `Nicknames` = :nicknames
WHERE ID = :cid
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how an `UPDATE` query works:

```
UPDATE `directory` SET `First_Name` = :firstname, `Surname` = :surname, `Nicknames` = :nicknames WHERE ID = :cid
```

I suggest you look into how sql in general works, because just guessing will not get you very far. The syntax you tried to use is for an `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for a SQL update is not the same as for an insert

```
UPDATE `directory` 
   SET `First_Name` = :firstname,
       `Surname` = :surname,
       `Nicknames` = :nicknames
 WHERE `ID` = :cid
```

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement is wrong. It should be:

```
   update directory set firstname=:firstname, surname=:surname, ...;
```